# Application crashes when sending to different device

Tags: android

I have developed a few applications and run them on my phone and they work well. But when I send them to different phone they won't open even when I try to reinstall them on my phone from the APK file they stop working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: add your log file please, do you send  signed apk for debug one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you share your app which install from android studio directly. That app cannot able to run in other devices.

So, Build apk file in android studio and then share that apk file to your friends. It will run smoothly/